# is there any function in mysql 8 to find specific key with its specific value?

Tags: mysql, sql, json

record in column named as athjc contains this json data

```
{
    "1": [
        "1",
        "2",
        "3",
        "11",
        "36",
        "s1"
    ],
    "20": [
        "s1",
        "s2",
        "s3"
    ],
    "name": "atharva"
}
```

I want to find out a record which contains key="20" and value= "s1"
how to achieve this using JSON functions available in MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have JSON_EXTRACT function in your mysql then you may use following query.

> JSON_EXTRACT(YOUR_KEY_NAME, "$.YOUR_KEY_VALUE")

Otherwise you may use SUBSTR function to achieve this. If you are novice in database or still confusion how to do this. You may visit [this](https://www.go4smart.com). They'll make a function for you to achieve your desired output.

Thanks

Comment: Here is another solution.

SELECT user_name,
LOWER(TRIM(BOTH 0x22 FROM TRIM(BOTH 0x20 FROM SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(user_name,LOCATE('\"20\"',user_name)+LENGTH('\"20\"'),LOCATE(0x2C,SUBSTRING(user_name,LOCATE('\"20\"',user_name)+LENGTH('\"20\"')+1,LENGTH(user_name)))),LOCATE(0x22,SUBSTRING(user_name,LOCATE('\"20\"',user_name)+LENGTH('\"20\"'),LOCATE(0x2C,SUBSTRING(user_name,LOCATE('\"20\"',user_name)+LENGTH('\"20\"')+1,LENGTH(user_name))))),LENGTH(user_name)))))
FROM tbl_users